# What kind of data is in Google Chrome's Extension State directory?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

What kind of data is the content of Google Chrome's **Extension State** directory? It seems to have something to do with extensions, it's being held while the browser is running & removing the data does not seem to have any obvious effect on the installed extensions' state or settings (at least with a synced account).

It can typically be found at *%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extension State* (Default stands for user profile).

Answer (score 0):

While not documented, that folder is typically used to store one specific thing:

- Items added by the extension to `chrome.contextMenus`

There may be more uses for it, but this is all that I've found through testing.

The files include `ldb` locks for the databases used, a `log` history of interactions with the context menu, and databases storing the added context menu items.